# Assigning Users to Accesss Levels

Tags: joomla-3.4

Can someone please show me how to assign a user to the access level shown in image 'No Access2'?

Carlton[image: access levels]

Comment: You assign a user to an access level. You can assign user groups to access levels. And you can assign access levels to content. And can assign usesr to user groups. I think you are a little confused with the Joomla ACL logic.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the instruction: [image: instruction]

1. Go to User Groups Create
2. User Group "No Access"
3. Go to Access Levels page
4. Create Access Level "No Access2"
5. While doing step 4 - pick any User Groups you want.
6. Save - and you're ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Users -> Manage, choose the user you want to edit, go to Assigned User Group tab, then checkout the user group item you want.

Comment: webchun, I can't seem to create a User Group to add the access level 'No Access2' to it.

Comment: I'm trying to create a 'User Group' called 'Group No Access' and then add the access level 'No Access2' to the group and then assign a user to that group